# Calender Sync across multiple devices and platforms

Tags: cross-platform, knowledge-organization, optimization

I'm looking to optimize the way my fiance and i sync our calenders. Our current system (we are both within the Apple OSX/iPhone environments) uses a combination of Avocado (an app for couples) and Wunderlist. However, I'm having difficulty with getting everything to sync in a neat manner. Ideally this is what I'm looking for.

1. Wunderlist Date syncs on my iPhone and her iPhone
2. Ideally something to Sync our Avocado dates with, or maybe a way to transition out of Avocado, the main appeal of which is that both she and I can add dates to the shared calender feature.
3. Syncs with my Work outlook calenders (there are multiple)
4. Ideally plays nice with the Moleskine Timepage calender app (my favorite)

My Fiance currently uses the following

1. iCal on her computer and Phone (Which apparently aren't synced, but i think thats a different matter)
2. Acovado for our relationship stuff
3. Cozy (another app for stuff with her family)
4. Wunderlist
5. No work calender for her as she has a seperate work phone for that.

Can anyone help me sort out this tangled web of calenders?

Thank you.

Comment: You could setup your own [ownCloud](https://owncloud.org/) server (or look for a provider offering you an account), and simply use its calendar for that. It uses CalDAV, which definitely works with Mac. I use it with my Android devices and my Linux PCs this way. No idea on Avocado, Wunderlist etc., though, as I've never worked with that.

Comment: Thats a good idea. I may just force a move away from the Cozy/Avocado Apps because I think its kind of a crutch which maybe is good for one or two things, just encourages this kind of fragmentation.

Comment: If you use the icloud calendar built-into the phone you should just be able to turn on calendar sharing ( and give her account read-write permissions) and they should auto-sync with no additional software.  There is a icloud outlook sync add-on for that.  I share calendars with google calendar all the time and it always syncs automatically,  I can't imagine apple would be any different.  I send out movie invites to my whole family and they can even accept or decline the event.  Add email to notification list and changes will be auto notified.